# Using C++ template framework in Java

Tags: java, c++, templates, java-native-interface, wrapper

I'm currently on a school project, we made a FuzzyLogicFramework in C++.
Now, I try to use this framework in Java in order to do an android app using the framework, I have a factory called **FuzzyFactory** in the c++ project. 
the prototype for its methods are like this :
`Expression<T>* newAnd(Expression<T>*, Expression<T>*);`

I don't necesserly want to use all the avaiable types that is why I created a class like this :

`template<> class FuzzyFactory<float>;`

I generated a DLL library with this class.

My questions are the following:
   I want to use this library in a Java file : what technology could I use? 
I heard about JNI and was able to run basic functions with it, but would I be able to manage objects instanciation ? How would I be able to give pointers in my functions arguments in Java ? I was able to run my c++ project main in Java using **JNI**, but it seems using a Factory class with it is on another level.

I also heard about **wrappers** and **JNA**

I just need somebody to told me a technology to use, It's my first time trying to do cross language implementation so I'm a bit overwhelmed.

if you want to see a bit more about the current state of the project : https://gitlab.com/MelvinC/languageframeworkproject-ensisa-2020

Should my Java project and c++ project be in the same git repository ?

Sorry for my english, if it is not good enough.

Thank you in advance for reading and helping me.

Comment: The value of a C++ pointer can be represented in Java as a `long`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWIG has some support for C++ templates and can generate Java binding code from C++ headers. That will give you a very low-level, but hopefully usable interface.

Alternatively, you might want to consider some sort of external representation of your logic program. You can then use plain Java code to construct the program, then serialize it into the external representation and pass it to the C++ side.
For inspiration, the Z3 SMT solver accepts a representation called [SMT-LIB](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/language.shtml).
Alternatively, you can create your own format using S-expressions, XML, or even just nested JSON.

Comment: @Jean-BaptistedelaBroise if Botje has answered your question, please accept his/her solution